# Getting wrong answer from a comparison XSL

Tags: xslt-1.0

So this is fairly simple I think, it could be more involved then I understand though.

Anyways, at the moment I'll just include the code I believe to be relevant, if someone thinks that more would be relevant then I will try to include more.

I've got two statements:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$isOnlineColumnEmpty" />
<xsl:value-of select="not($isOnlineColumnEmpty = 'false')" />
```

The first one outputs false. However, the second one is outputting true, which is the opposite of what I expect.

In addition to this, These two statements get repeated multiple times, and I only get this result in one section. However, there is absolutely no code in between these two statements, so nothing could be changing the value of the variable.

Just wondering if there is something I could be overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured this out later.

Changing the statement to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$isOnlineColumnEmpty != false" />
```

Fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="not($isOnlineColumnEmpty = 'false')" />
```

**use**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="not($isOnlineColumnEmpty = false())" />
```

**Explanation**:

The *boolean value* `false()` is something different from the *string* `"false"`.

When a boolean is compared to another value, the second value is converted to a boolean and then the comparisson is performed. To quote the **[XPath 1.0 W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans)**:

> "*If at least one object to be compared is a boolean, then each object
>   to be compared is converted to a boolean as if by applying the boolean
>   function*."

So, in this concrete case the string `"false"` is converted to boolean. By definition `boolean($someString)` is `true()` for any non-empty string.

Therefore, after the conversion the two boolean values `false()` and `true()` are compared and the result is `false()`. Because in the original expression this result is argument to the `not()` function, the final result is `not(false())` , that is `true()`.

**Here is the chain of calculations**:

```
not($isOnlineColumnEmpty = 'false') ==> not(false() = 'false') ==>

not(false() = boolean(false())) ==> not(false() = true()) ==>

not(false()) ==> true()
```

Comment: Very helpful answer. Doesn't work in my case due to the variables being done in such a way that they aren't actually booleans, they just wish they were. But helpful none the less, and definitely the correct way of doing things.